# Replace locally mapped drive network letter with another letter

Tags: networking, drive

Most of our users have mapped drives to their local machines with the letters that I want to use to in a script that will map network drives to all users.
I will like to replace those letters with another letter and use my network letters to map their network drives.
I have a script to delete those letters and use the network drive letters I want but I do not want to delete their mapped drives, I just want to replace their mapped drives with another letter if the mapped drives is the same as the letter I want to use.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the **net use** command in a batch file:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx

First delete the old connection and then create a new one...